# How to get explode @img::value to lookup in my database

Tags: php

I want to get value from my content such as `@img::56`:

`@img::56 => value=56` to get record from datatabase `mysql_query("select * from tblgallery where g_id=56");`.

> Tara Angkor Hotel is the first 4-Star Luxury Hotel built in the mystical land of Angkor. **@img::56** Ideally and **@youtube::https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4YRWT_Aldo** conveniently located, Tara Angkor Hotel is situated only 6 km from the World Heritage site of Angkor Wat Temples, 15 min drive from the Siem Reap International Airport, a few minutes stroll to the Angkor National Museum and **@img::41** a short ride to the city town center with an array of Cambodian souvenirs, shopping and culture.

I want to get result

> Tara Angkor Hotel is the first 4-Star Luxury Hotel built in the mystical land of Angkor. **mysql_query("select * from tblgallery where g_id=56")** Ideally and **<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/k4YRWT_Aldo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>** conveniently located, Tara Angkor Hotel is situated only 6 km from the World Heritage site of Angkor Wat Temples, 15 min drive from the Siem Reap International Airport, a few minutes stroll to the Angkor National Museum and **mysql_query("select * from tblgallery where g_id=41")** a short ride to the city town center with an array of Cambodian souvenirs, shopping and culture.

Comment: And... your code is...?

Comment: (Hint: [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) may be the tool you need)

Comment: (You don't need to use HTML entities here to show HTML -just paste your HTML into the box, select it and click the code button).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to retrieve the 56 from the string `@img::56`?

If so it can be done as follows.

```
$string = '@img::56';

// Explode the string as the delimiter.
$components = explode('::', $string);

// Ensure the components array has two elements.
if(count($components) < 2) {

   // Do something here to indicate an error has occurred. 
   //Throw an exception (preferred) or emit an error

}

$id = $components[1];

// You can use even more type checking here to ensure you have the right piece of data.
if(!ctype_digit($id)) {

    //Throw an exception (preferred) or emit an error

}

// Accessing the database using a PDO object and prepared statements

$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=...', 'username', 'password')

$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblgallary WHERE g_id = :id');

$statement->bindParam(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);

if(!$statement->execute()) {

    //Throw an exception (preferred) or emit an error

}

$result = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// End the database connection
$pdo = null;
```

Now you have the id. If you need the `$id` to be an integer you can type cast it with `(int) $components[1]` instead.

Hope this helps.